# sqlalchemy store media in the database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want have a media table in my database but I want to store a video or photos in the database what is the best way to do that ? Do I have to store the path to the uploaded video in the file system or is it better to have a blob?

If I have to use a blob how can I store my media in the Database ?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better to store the image on the filesystem and store the path in the database.

database storage is usually more expensive than file system storage

A Great article [here](http://perspectives.mvdirona.com/2008/06/facebook-needle-in-a-haystack-efficient-storage-of-billions-of-photos/) on which type to use

Answer (score 4):

I use this library and it is very fast and simple: [sqlalchemy-media](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-media/)

I think this could be helpful to the newbie user like me.

with regards

Answer (score 2):

Generally better to store the asset on disk, and the path in the database. Returning (possibly) large blobs from the DB can be costly.

If you do store it as a blob in the DB, you can use a LargeBinary column, like:

```
blob = Column(LargeBinary)
```

Comment: Thanks for the blob column But after reading the article I think I'll go with the filesystem.