# Problem while inserting a text file/an image into SQlite using flask:python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a text file and an image into SQlite database but the code I'm using doesn't work,even though there are no errors displayed but it won't store anything in the BLOB image column of SQLite.I have been searching the internet but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

The python code I'm using is:

```
    data=sqlite3.Binary(f.read())

    new_file = Samples(Samplename=filename,imagefile=data)
    db.session.add(new_file)
    db.session.commit()
```

And plus I dont want to save the filepath ,I want to save the file itself,even if it is not a good practice.Kindly help.TIA

Comment: I hope this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930262/sqlalchemy-store-media-in-the-database

Comment: @jaswanth yeah i saw that but I want to store the file in database because it is needed for my application....

Comment: I suggest to store the json file on disk, and create a column "json_path" pointing to the json file in your history table.

Comment: did you check this [link](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-media/) in the other stackoverflow

Comment: @thomask  it did insert the file through sqlite console(using insert into query) but not through flask..any idea if that's possible at all?

Comment: @jaswanth how to save the path of JSON file in this case?

Comment: @Mary you can use `os.path.abspath("test4.txt")` to get the absolute path and store this in database when you need to access from database you can get path from datbase and read using `data = open(file_path, "r").read()` and access data

Comment: @thomask I have edited the question ,do you have any idea about the problem?